# PubSub: horizontally scaling subscriber forwarders

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

From the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#basic_architecture, We understand how pubsub can relay messages between publisher forwarders and subscriber forwarders and the image at the location https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/images/wp_msg_lifecycle.svg visualises this information.

From all the information provided, I could understand that, at any given point in time, the unacknowledged messages in multiple publish message sources can be consumed by a subscriber forwarder and total number of publish message sources depend on the publisher forwarders.

In a scenario where the data is supposed to be consumed in real time, how does pubsub scale the forwarders to achieve no backlog. Because, each publisher forwarder at any given point in time can connect to a single subscriber forwarder and as the scaling of publisher forwarder and subscriber forwarder is independent/decoupled this may increase backlog in the system as subscriber forwarder is supposed to relay multiple messages to the subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limitation that a publisher forwarder can only connect to a single subscriber forwarder, even though that is the example shown in the diagram. The limiting factor in end-to-end latency in Cloud Pub/Sub is very rarely ever the service itself; it is the subscriber client behavior. In particular, it is important to:

1. Have enough subscriber capacity to handle with the throughput.
2. Ack messages quickly, on the order of milliseconds or seconds.
3. Avoid nacking messages, particularly for push subscriptions, where nacks cause backoff in the delivery rate of messages.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick response. So basically, subscriber message delivery scaling is independent of the publishing and it (Subscriber message delivery) needs to scale both publisher forwarders and subscriber forwarders to allow fast and safe delivery without backlogs (as 1 publish message store is handled by 1 publisher forwarder and in case of constant delivery rate, same forwarder can be used after all messages in the publish message store are acked to avoid re-provisioning resources for forwarders).

Comment: Publishing and subscribing scaling is generally independent. It is part of the Pub/Sub pattern that publishing and subscribing should be independent and so the scaling reflects that. The publish side needs to scale with the amount of publishing (in terms of messages, bytes, and publisher count) and the subscribe side needs to scale with the amount of subscribing (in terms of messages, bytes, subscription count, and subscriber count). As with many Cloud services, Pub/Sub is designed such that users don't have to think about these internal details.